# C# Binary Tree 2D Packing Algorithm Rotation

Tags: c#, bin-packing

I'm using [Binary-Tree-2D-Packing](https://github.com/timskillman/Binary-Tree-2D-Packing) this algorithm to pack rectangles in a container. It works fine but I want to rotate the node if it's not fitting right of the root node. It should try width and height at the right node and if it's not fitting it should rotate it and make width = height and height = width then try again. How can I accomplish that?

```
public class Packer
        {
            public Packer()
            {
                boxes = new List<Box>();
            }
    public class Node
    {
        public Node right;
        public Node down;
        public double x;
        public double y;
        public double w;
        public double h;
        public bool used;
    }

    public class Box
    {
        public double height;
        public double width;
        public double area;
        public Node position;
    }

    public List<Box> boxes;
    private Node rootNode;

    public void AddBox(Box box)
    {
        box.area = box.width * box.height;
        boxes.Add(box);
    }

    public void Pack(double containerWidth, double containerHeight)
    {
        boxes = boxes.OrderByDescending(x => x.area).ToList();
        rootNode = new Node { w = containerWidth, h = containerHeight };

        foreach (var box in boxes)
        {
            var node = FindNode(rootNode, box.width, box.height);
            if (node != null)
            {
                box.position = SplitNode(node, box.width, box.height);
            }
            else
            {
                box.position = GrowNode(box.width, box.height);
            }
        }
    }

    private Node FindNode(Node rootNode, double w, double h)
    {
        if (rootNode.used)
        {
            var nextNode = FindNode(rootNode.right, w, h);

            if (nextNode == null)
            {
                nextNode = FindNode(rootNode.down, w, h);
            }

            return nextNode;
        }
        else if (w <= rootNode.w && h <= rootNode.h)
        {
            return rootNode;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private Node SplitNode(Node node, double w, double h)
    {
        
        node.used = true;
        node.down = new Node { x = node.x, y = node.y + h, w = node.w, h = node.h - h };
        node.right = new Node { x = node.x + w, y = node.y, w = node.w - w, h = h };
        return node;
    }

    private Node GrowNode(double w, double h)
    {
        bool canGrowDown = (w <= rootNode.w);
        bool canGrowRight = (h <= rootNode.h);

        bool shouldGrowRight = canGrowRight && (rootNode.h >= (rootNode.w + w));
        bool shouldGrowDown = canGrowDown && (rootNode.w >= (rootNode.h + h));

        if (shouldGrowRight)
        {

            return growRight(w, h);
        }
        else if (shouldGrowDown)
        {

            return growDown(w, h);
        }
        else if (canGrowRight)
        {

            return growRight(w, h);
        }
        else if (canGrowDown)
        {

            return growDown(w, h);
        }
        else
        {

            return null;
        }
    }

    private Node growRight(double w, double h)
    {
        rootNode = new Node()
        {
            used = true,
            x = 0,
            y = 0,
            w = rootNode.w + w,
            h = rootNode.h,
            down = rootNode,
            right = new Node() { x = rootNode.w, y = 0, w = w, h = rootNode.h }
        };

        Node node = FindNode(rootNode, w, h);
        if (node != null)
        {
            return SplitNode(node, w, h);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private Node growDown(double w, double h)
    {
        rootNode = new Node()
        {
            used = true,
            x = 0,
            y = 0,
            w = rootNode.w,
            h = rootNode.h + h,
            down = new Node() { x = 0, y = rootNode.h, w = rootNode.w, h = h },
            right = rootNode
        };
        Node node = FindNode(rootNode, w, h);
        if (node != null)
        {
            return SplitNode(node, w, h);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `auto temp = width; width = height; height = temp`?

Comment: @0liveradam8 I know how to rotate rectangle I don't know how to automatically control it and check for available rotations.

Comment: unrelated, why isn't `area` a calculated property? `public double Area => height*width;`

Comment: Add a variable in `Node` if it rotated or not. Keep `side1` and `side2` and present the `Width` and `Height` depending on if the node is rotated or not.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou can you show an example with a little piece of code, I already added a rotated bool variable in Node but I couldn't get the rest.

Comment: I don't know enough about the algorithm to know where to place the check for fitting a rotated box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added rotated variable to `Node`

```
public class Node
    {
        public Node right;
        public Node down;
        public double x;
        public double y;
        public double w;
        public double h;
        public bool used;
        public bool rotated;
    }
```

And added rotation condition to `FindNode` method

```
private Node FindNode(Node rootNode, double w, double h)
    {
        if (rootNode.used)
        {

            var nextNode = FindNode(rootNode.right, w, h);

            if (nextNode == null)
            {

                nextNode = FindNode(rootNode.right, h, w);
                if (nextNode!=null) { nextNode.rotated = true; }
                
                if (nextNode == null)
                {
                    nextNode = FindNode(rootNode.down, w, h);
                }

            }

            return nextNode;
        }
        else if (w <= rootNode.w && h <= rootNode.h)
        {
            return rootNode;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

At last checked for the rotated variable if true,

```
public void Pack(double containerWidth, double containerHeight)
    {
        boxes = boxes.OrderByDescending(x => x.area).ToList();
        rootNode = new Node { w = containerWidth, h = containerHeight };

        foreach (var box in boxes)
        {
            var node = FindNode(rootNode, box.width, box.height);
            if (node != null)
            {

            
            if (node.rotated)
            {
                double tmp = 0;
                tmp = box.width;
                box.width = box.height;
                box.height = tmp;
            }
            }
            if (node != null)
            {
                box.position = SplitNode(node, box.width, box.height);
            }
            else
            {
                box.position = GrowNode(box.width, box.height);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

unless I missunderstand something, would it not just be a two tests instead of one? I.e.

```
        var node = FindNode(rootNode, box.width, box.height);
        if (node != null)
        {
            box.position = SplitNode(node, box.width, box.height);
        }
        else
        {
            node = FindNode(rootNode, box.height, box.width);
            if(node!= null){
                  box.position = SplitNode(node, box.height, box.width);
            }

            box.position = GrowNode(box.width, box.height);
        }
```

Note that the `GrowNode` would always grow in width-height order.

If the tree where immutable you could also try each alternative and compare the resulting nodes.:

```
       Node whNode, hwNode;

       var node = FindNode(rootNode, box.width, box.height);           
        if (node != null)
        {
            whNode = SplitNode(node, box.width, box.height);
        }
        else
        {
            whNode = GrowNode(box.width, box.height);
        }

        node = FindNode(rootNode, box.height, box.width);
        if (node != null)
        {
            hwNode= SplitNode(node, box.height, box.width);
        }
        else
        {
            hwNode= GrowNode(box.height, box.width);
        }
        box.Position = GetBestNode(whNode, hwNode);
```

Comment: I tried the first one it didn't work but I couldn't try the second one because I don't have a method called GetBestNode, are you telling me to create one?

Comment: Yes, you would need to supply such a method. And it would only work correctly if the tree where immutable, and that does not seem to be the case in your example.

Comment: Yes it's constantly mutates, this won't work for me I guess.